# Xcode workspace reference project by environment variable

Tags: xcode, workspace

I need to reference a project in a Xcode workspace by an environment variable. An Xcode workspace file might look like this:

```
<Workspace
   version = "1.0">
   <FileRef
      location = "group:../../Some/Dir/SomeLibrary.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "group:SomeApp/SomeApp.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
</Workspace>
```

I want the SomeLibrary project to be referenced by an environment variable, so that the workspace file and projects can be used in different developer environments (the lib project is shared between several different projects). Any ideas on how to do this? Is the XML-format documented somewhere?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I need to answer this myself. Based on my research it is not possible to use a dynamic location (environment variable, source tree, etc) on workspace projects.

Solution 1:
You CAN achieve what I'm trying to do using symlinks. In my current workspace I've created one application-project, and a project entry which points to a symlink on the local file system. This way one can switch projects and have dynamic locations for the library-projects. I'm not sure if XCode treated this link properly when adding, so I manually added the project entry like this:

```
<FileRef
    location = "group:Libraries/SomeLibrary/SomeLibrary.xcodeproj">
</FileRef>
```

Where SomeLibrary (IMPORTANT: The folder SomeLibrary need to be the symlink, or else XCode wont be able to find the project contents) is a symlink to my static library project somewhere else on the local file system. This way, developers can have different paths to the library, and one can easily switch versions when needed.

Solution 2:
Adding a static library project as a subproject and using cross-reference. For sub-projects, one can use Source Tree and use dynamic locations.

I haven't tested these solutions widely, so I'll come back with a reply after using it for a while.

Answer (score 3):

In your XCode 4 Preferences, you'll see a "Locations" tab and in the "Source Trees" section you can put an environment-variable like location (which you can change from machine to machine).  And you can use these settings to change paths for the libraries you're trying to include or reference in your projects.

It's not exactly the environment variable from the Terminal command line, but then again most people don't launch XCode from the Terminal and so you shouldn't expect to pick up your $PATH or other UNIX-style environment variables from double clicking on any app, much less the XCode IDE.  It's a good alternative.

There's some more information [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982133/what-is-source-tree-in-the-xcode-preferences-and-what-can-i-do-with-it) and here's [Apple's documentation on what they are and how to set them up](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-source_trees_preferences/About.html) (which is aimed at XCode 3 but the same concepts apply for XCode 4).

Let me know if I can provide more information, and I hope my answer helps!

Comment: Thank you, it looks very promising. Tho I can see that this might work for the developers (only took a brief look at it). However, projects are built using build servers, and they need to be able to build it from the command line (forgot to mention the command line part in the original question). I'm not sure how this can be accomplished using the same technique.

Comment: Hopefully you can have all your build servers set up in an identical manner (with similar Source Tree variable declarations).  You can keep different libraries on different build servers, if that's what you're trying to do. Just have the library path in your project depend on the Source Tree variables and you might be able to find your solution there.  Also, if you're building on build servers, investigate the `xcodebuild` tool and `.xcconfig` files. That might be another potential solution for you.

Comment: Yes, I'll look into that. However, I just tried the Source Tree technique. It seems that you can choose location for files IN a project relative to the source tree variables, for projects themselves however, the source tree paths are not present in the dropdown.

Comment: The source tree paths *are* present in the "Location" drop downs in XCode's File Inspector.  For example, click on an .a library or .m/.h file and open up the File Inspector and under the Location pop-up menu, you'll see, along with "Relative to Group" or "Relative to Project", will be "Relative to (Insert Your Source Tree Name)" entries as well.

Comment: Yes, you do, but if you click on a project in a workspace, the Source Tree options are gone :)

Comment: Check my answer below Michael Dautermann, please comment if you see any problems with my two (well, the first prefferably) solutions.