# Relative path folder issue with Header Search Path in XCode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

We have added a subproject in our main project, located in folder /Users/(user-name)/git/common/**, so it's not located as subfolder in the main project. I want to share my project with other developers, and I have tried to use relative path in Header Search Paths option:

../../git/common/**

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in these situations is to put my SDK into its own folder, then told Xcode about that location via the "Source Trees" entry in the "Location" section of its preferences. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982133/what-is-source-tree-in-the-xcode-preferences-and-what-can-i-do-with-it) for more details on how Source Trees work.